# GUI for web search history

Tags: python, tkinter, wxpython

I'm absolute beginner to python. I am building a web-history tracker, which tracks user's web history and accessed time. And I want to create a GUI with a button and display the user's history once they click the button.I have watched so many videos and yet didn't get the idea to link the code with the button to get the output. If some life savior could help me with this it would be highly appreciated. Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/354577)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my most basic GUI skeleton that I use to start my GUI applications. Just so I don't have to remember the initial setup every time.

```
import tkinter as tk

class OOP:
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = tk.Tk()
        self.win.title("My Title")
        self.create_widgets()

    def click_me(self): # this is how you set up functions to run on button clicks
        print("button was clicked")

    def create_widgets(self):
        tk.Label(self.win, text="My GUI").pack(expand=1, fill='both')
        tk.Button(self.win, text="Click ME", command=self.click_me).pack(expand=1, fill='both')

app = OOP()
app.win.mainloop()
```

You can look up information about how to fill it out all over the web. I use http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/ as a main reference point though. If you want more help you will have to post an actual question that needs solving

Comment: thank you so much for your guidance. I'll go through this and check it. really appreciate your help

Comment: No problem! Obviously a thorough description of GUI is outside the scope of a single forum post (hence why several people down-voted the post), but if this helps you on your path then you could accept the answer and the thread will close (click the check mark by my post, you'll also recover some reputation and get a badge). You can also read "Python GUI programming cookbook" published by Packt, between that book and the previously linked website that's a great start to building GUIs.